# Load MatDialog component on page init

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a check to see if a user has logged in for the first time 
 This routes them to my member page where they have to fill in some personal details before they can access other modules
I would like to pop up a MatDialog with T's&C's which thee user has to accept first before foing anything else, when they decline a logout will occur.

Is there any example I can look at where this works I have searched a bit to no avail.

Using angular 11 for the front end with restful .net core 3.1 API

I want a dialog MatDialog to popup on the ngOnInit function if the User property has a first time login of true:

[Section that should fire popup of dialog on NgOnInit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL7tY.png)

[Component to pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjZ3v.png)

Comment: Please provide the code that you are using.

Comment: Try calling `this.dialog.open(TsAndCsCompoenet)` inside your ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit.